# Google Maps - Setting print preferences via querystring parameters

Tags: printing, parameters, maps

I'm putting a link onto a site to allow my visitors to print off a map and directions from Google Maps. At the moment I have something this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=newcastle&daddr=london&pw=2

Is there a parameter I can add to this URL that will cause the "include large map?" checkbox at the top of the page to be checked by default when the page is loaded? Its not a big problem but will save my users a click :)

Thanks